# Redirect a non existent directory to a normal directory using .htaccess on Joomla

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla, directory

I would like to ask how is possible to redirect an non existent directory to a normal directory. Or even better, how is it possible to remove a directory from the url.

Example:
When the url is `www.mysite.com/bad_directory/images/and/sub/directories` I want it to be `www.mysite.com/images/and/sub/directories`. In other words I want the directory "bad_directory/" to be removed when directory "images" is requested.

Comment: You can use sh404 componenent that make easy redirection

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line in your .htaccess file :

```
RewriteRule ^bad_directory/images/and/sub/directories$ /images/and/sub/directories [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution

At .htcaccess file, I added the line:

```
RedirectMatch ^/bad/directory/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/good-directory/$1
```